# Transcribe android java code to Objective-C Xcode

Tags: java, android, objective-c, xcode

I know a bit Android java, and i have to realise an app already done in this langage to adapt it in Objective-C via Xcode.
The problem is that i'm too new to Objective-C langage. I realised several tutorials, so i'm not completely lost in this langage. But i would like to know classes/functions that match in those langage.
I would like you to tell me how to translate the code below from Android Java to Obj-C Xcode

```
public class ThreadRecuperationIP extends Thread
{
    static ThreadRecuperationIP thread;

    protected ThreadRecuperationIP()
    {
        super();
        thread = this;
        start();
    }

        public static void demarrer()
    {
        if (thread == null || !thread.isAlive())
        {
            thread = new ThreadRecuperationIP();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is only a small part of the code.
If you guys could help me to translate this code to Obj-C, that would help me a lot to understand how to do & understand the logic.
I don't know if what i ask is complicated, but i hope that some guy will be able to help me :)

Comment: You might want to try this (http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2012/09/j2objc-java-to-ios-objective-c.html) from Google

Comment: I saw it before, but i've never tried it... Does it work very well ? i heard that it was an alpha / beta version, & i'm too new in obj-C langage to fix errors that could happen if it doesn't work well.

Comment: To be very frank... I have not tried it myself yet but I have heard that it is pretty good.

Comment: If you want this code to be converted to obj-c, I must tell you, obj-c 's NSThread is not as much powerful as Java's. However obj-c uses few other things like operaton queue, GCD to accomplish the multithreading task. So directly converting this code to obj-c is beyond expectation. If you want to convert some basic code then its ok :)

Comment: Ok ;) i'm really going to try this so ! Thanks for your answers :)